# KDE Plasma crashes after logging in

Tags: kde, plasma

I just bought an ultra wide 3440 x 1440 monitor made by LG and tried to use it with my Linux Debian 8.

I decided to use Display Port, since HDMI < 2.0 is limited to a maximum frequency of 30 Hertz.

My problem is that while it perfectly works as long as Gnome is used as desktop environment, it instantly crashes after logging in KDE Plasma with no more output signal.